# PHP script check in plugged in USB

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask, whether is it possible for PHP to check the plugged in USB drive and show the windows drive that it use, and parse it into the form?

If it possible, how do i do it?

Comment: Short answer: No. If the PHP script is not on the USB drive (autorun) as hd suggest, you will always need some other tool that tells the PHP script that an USB device has been plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

use a php system() or exec() function to call out to a windows batch command. The batch command would have to find the USB drive. Perhaps you could list all drives, and use the drive 'label' to identify which line contained the drive letter you were interested in, eg D:> '4GB FLASH DRIVE'

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a file on the USB device you could try somthing like:

```
$AtoZ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$USBDRIVE = "";
for ($i=0; $i < 27; $i++) {
     $filename = $AtoZ[$i].':/usb.txt';
         if (file_exists($filename)) {
              $USBDRIVE = $AtoZ . ":/";
          }
}
```